# How to create a QPushButtton with 2 borders using style sheets?

Tags: qt, stylesheet

I'm trying to use style sheets to customize a QPushButton.  Using the following style sheet I have create a button with a gray background and a black boarder around it :

```
 background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97); 
 border-style: outset;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 border-radius: 4px;
 color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

I'd like to add a second border around the button using the style sheet.  I tried setting a padding color, but that does not seem to do anything.  Is it possible to add a second border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use only style sheet it's probably not possible.

Similar solution is to change border-style to *double*, e.g.

```
background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
border-style: double;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-radius: 4px;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

All [available borders](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-style).

Relating to padding it's not possible to set a color for it. Explain how it look is [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the button with a QFrame, and style that QFrame in addition to the QPushButton.

```
//    ------Widget------
//      ------hbox----------
//        ------QFrame---------
//          ------frameLayout-----
//            ------QPushButton-----

QHBoxLayout * hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
QFrame * frame = new QFrame;
QPushButton * button = new QPushButton("Double Border Button");
QHBoxLayout * frameLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
frameLayout->addWidget(button);
frame->setLayout(frameLayout);
hbox->addWidget(frame);
this->setLayout(hbox);
```

Hope that helps.